# Does it make sense to use on every spring boot service an interface?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, coding-style, clean-architecture

Which kind of design pattern speaks for and which against having an interface on every Service in Spring / SpringBoot?

Or does it only make sense to use Interfaces for services if at least you use two different implementations for a given interface.

What is the advantage to use an interface if you only have always one implementation in your code base.

Comment: Until you reach the max number of methods in one object.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your question with: it depends.

If you think about the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), especially the [Interface Seggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), and its importance in object-oriented design:

> Within object-oriented design, interfaces provide layers of abstraction that simplify code and create a barrier preventing coupling to dependencies.

The interfaces are using to expose the API contracts without exposing their implementation.

But, as I said before, it depends on the use case.
Let's say you're building a library/framework where it can expose multiple implementations for the same interface or allow the users to add their implementations. Then you surely should have interfaces.

On the other hand, it can also lead to [some overengineering](https://blog.frankel.ch/are-you-guilty-of-overengineering/) where your interface has only one implementation, you are sure it won't have more than one implementation, and it won't be used outside of your application. Then maybe you could skip it.

So, from my point of view, it depends.